# Multiple producer consumers working simultaneously in C#

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I want to understand the most generic usage of producer /consumer pattern in C#.
The following are the conditions that I have thought of:

- The producers are pushing in data continuously.
- The consumers are picking up (processing and removing) data continuously.
- The speed of either operation can be much higher in proportion over another.
- No two consumers should get the same data.

I know TPL, .Net 4.x etc. give a lot of classes to handle such a scenario. But before delving into all those classes it is imperative to know what problem are they solving. I would appreciate if someone can point me to some article/resource/sample that solves this using traditional Monitor/lock and Thread classes.

There is a high chance that somebody comes running shouting this question is not constructive or what have I done so far. Please trust me I have done some google search and could not find anything that matches all the criteria meeting above conditions. All examples are either single producer or single consumer or using newer classes. Please excuse me if I am trying to solve an insane problem. But please mention why do you think it is wrong.

I am not looking for spoon fed answers or implementations right away as I know it requires good deal of code. I am just asking for pointers where I can find something to help me with the implementation. Although I would appreciate a little explanation if your kindness (aka time) permits!

Thanks for reading.

Comment: I strongly suggest you take a look at TPL Dataflow which is *specifically* geared towards the kind of scenario you explain.

Comment: Can you tell us what you've come up with so far ? `with code` and without google? You mention you have searched, yet no links...  Please elaborate why a simple publisher/subscriber model with SignalR isn't any good...

Comment: Jeremy,
The question is open ended. SignalR isn't good because I am not looking the answer for a web application.
I did not give the details of the exact application I am working on because I want you to help me with just this problem.
Here is the link for implementation using dataflow:
http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/11/async-producerconsumer-queue-using.html
But I have reasons to not go for TPL and newer classes.
I will eventually start coding once I know what am I trying to solve.
Btw, I will appreciate if you can get a link that solves the problem without TPL and new classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some ancient test code I had lying around. It uses .Net 3.x era classes to implement a threadsafe producer/consumer queue.

Because this is so old, it has some gnarly bits - such as the publicly-exposed `SyncLock` property. I would never expose this publicly in real code!

However, this code does at least illustrate a working producer/consumer queue that's implemented using basic constructs.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;

namespace Demo
{
    public sealed class ProducerConsumerQueue<T>: IEnumerable<T>
    {
        /// <summary>Has the queue been closed?</summary>

        public bool IsClosed
        {
            get
            {
                return _isClosed;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>The object used to synchronize access to the queue.</summary>

        public object SyncLock
        {
            get
            {
                return _syncLock;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>Tell the queue that no more items will be added.</summary>
        /// <param name="waitUntilEmpty">Wait until the queue is empty before returning?</param>

        public void Close(bool waitUntilEmpty)
        {
            lock (_syncLock)
            {
                _isClosed = true;
                Monitor.PulseAll(_syncLock);     // Wake up all consumers.

                if (waitUntilEmpty)
                {
                    while (_queue.Count > 0)
                    {
                        Monitor.Wait(_syncLock);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>Adds an item the the queue.</summary>
        /// <param name="item">The item to be added.</param>

        public void Add(T item)
        {
            lock (_syncLock)
            {
                if (_isClosed)
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("The queue has been closed.");
                }

                _queue.Enqueue(item);

                if (_queue.Count == 1)
                {
                    Monitor.Pulse(_syncLock);    // Added first item to the queue; wake up a consumer.
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>Typesafe Enumerator access to the queue items.</summary>

        public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                T item;

                lock (_syncLock)
                {
                    if (_queue.Count > 0)
                    {
                        item = _queue.Dequeue();

                        if (_isClosed && (_queue.Count == 0))
                        {
                            Monitor.PulseAll(_syncLock);    // Tell producer we're done.
                        }
                    }
                    else if (_isClosed)
                    {
                        yield break;                // All done.
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Monitor.Wait(_syncLock);    // Waits for another item to enter the queue or the queue to be closed.
                        continue;                   // Back to "while".
                    }
                }

                yield return item;  // Yield outside of the lock.
            }
        }

        /// <summary>Non-typesafe Enumerator access to the queue items.</summary>

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return GetEnumerator();
        }


        private readonly Queue<T> _queue = new Queue<T>();
        private readonly object _syncLock = new object();

        private bool _isClosed;
    }

    public static class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            ProducerConsumerQueue<string> queue = new ProducerConsumerQueue<string>();

            // Spawn first consumer thread.

            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem
            (
                delegate
                {
                    foreach (string item in queue)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Consumer 1 is consuming: " + item);
                        randomSleep(200); // simulate business
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine("Consumer 1 exited cleanly.");
                }
            );

            // Spawn second consumer thread.

            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem
            (
                delegate
                {
                    foreach (string item in queue)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Consumer 2 is consuming: " + item);
                        randomSleep(250); // simulate business
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine("Consumer 2 exited cleanly.");
                }
            );

            // Spawn third consumer thread.

            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem
            (
                delegate
                {
                    foreach (string item in queue)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Consumer 3 is consuming: " + item);
                        randomSleep(300); // simulate business
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine("Consumer 3 exited cleanly.");
                }
            );

            // Spawn first producer thread.

            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem
            (
                delegate
                {
                    for (int i = 0;; i++)
                    {
                        lock (queue.SyncLock)
                        {
                            if (!queue.IsClosed)
                            {
                                string item = "Producer 1 Item " + i.ToString();
                                Console.WriteLine("Producer 1 is adding: " + item);
                                queue.Add(item);
                            }
                        }

                        if (i < 50)     // Slowly add the first 50.
                        {
                            randomSleep(500); // simulate business
                        }
                        else            // Quickly add the remainder to get a backlog.
                        {
                            randomSleep(150); // simulate business
                        }
                    }
                }
            );

            // Spawn second producer thread.

            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem
            (
                delegate
                {
                    for (int i = 0;; i++)
                    {
                        lock (queue.SyncLock)
                        {
                            if (!queue.IsClosed)
                            {
                                string item = "Producer 2 Item " + i.ToString();
                                Console.WriteLine("Producer 2 is adding: " + item);
                                queue.Add(item);
                            }
                        }

                        if (i < 50)     // Slowly add the first 50.
                        {
                            randomSleep(600); // simulate business
                        }
                        else            // Quickly add the remainder to get a backlog.
                        {
                            randomSleep(120); // simulate business
                        }
                    }
                }
            );

            Thread.Sleep(20000);                        // Allow a few seconds for things to happen.
            Console.WriteLine("Closing queue...");
            queue.Close(true);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Console.WriteLine("Press [return] to exit");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void randomSleep(int max)
        {
            int delay;

            lock (_random)
            {
                delay = _random.Next(max + 100);
            }

            if (delay > 100)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(delay-100);
            }
        }

        static readonly Random _random = new Random();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. I will get back once I have tried and analysed it. I vote up for trying to help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use an actual queue system. [ZeroMQ](http://zeromq.org/) is lightening fast and has decent .NET bindings.